# Pull data / Replicate list data form Moss 2007 version site to SharePoint Online version site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, javascript

We have one requirement where we need to pull data / Replicate list data form Moss 2007 version site to SharePoint Online version site.

Please can any one suggest what are the approaches are available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach should be do it programmatically. Read the data form sharepoint with server object model or Web services and then add the data to Sharepoint Online using sharepoint Client object model.

Check : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/himanshukumar/archive/2012/05/22/how-to-migrate-sharepoint-2007-to-office-365-standard-using-native-web-service-and-csom.aspx

OR use other 3rd party tools like http://en.share-gate.com/office-365-migration